# How to add cpp rest sdk (cassablanca) to a project in VSCode on Mac

Tags: c++, rest, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

I am trying to install and add cpprestsdk to my c++ project and I cannot seem to figure out how to do so.

I have followed the instructions here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/How-to-build-for-Mac-OS-X

that have me build and run test on the cassablanca package, which worked successfully.

Then I tried to follow this guide:

https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial

But when trying to include the header files such as :

```
#include "<cpprest/http_client.h>"
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
```

I get an error when running my make file.

I have been trying to find some documentation on how to actually add the files into my build when compiling but have not been able to find anything.

Here is what my makefile is:

```
CC := g++
CFLAGS := -std=c11

csrc = $(wildcard src/*.cpp) \
       $(wildcard include/*.hpp) \
       $(wildcard libs/*)

obj = $(csrc:.c=.o) 

LDFLAGS = -Wall -lcpprest


localcoin: $(obj)
    $(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

When running make I get a huge stream of errors originating from the cassablanca installed files.

I am new to programming in c++ / C so have little experience with makefiles.

My question is then, how can I add cpprestsdk into my project so I can successfully use the library?

Thank you very much for your time, and any critiques or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I never figured it out, decided to install a VM running Linux and installed it there successfully